# Serializing a string to JSON, with a variable name

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a C# string property, to a variable declaration... *basically I don't want the surrounding quotation marks*. I have a variable declared in a separate `.js` file, and I want to be able to reference that in my JSON object. I'm using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for all of my serializing.

- Is this possible?
- Does this break the standard of JSON?

**C# Structure**

```
public class Settings
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
}
```

**Current JSON**

```
"{ Colour: 'MyApp.settings.colours' }"
```

**Desired JSON**

```
"{ Colour: MyApp.settings.colours }"
```

Comment: `MyApp.settings.colours` is not internally complete, though; it isn't really a great option. It'll work in *javascript* object construction, but **only** if `MyApp.settings` resolves in the current scope. In vanilla JSON: I'm not sure it has a defined meaning by itself. So: **why** do you want it without the quotes? It is a `string`. `string`s need start/end quotes.

Comment: If it was me, I would use the `returnedObject.Colour` to *access* the defined colours; something like `var colour = MyApp.settings.colours[returnedObject.Colour];`. Also, while I share your appreciation of the `u` in `colour`, in programming terms: `color` wins; `colour` will just lead to problems, IMO

Comment: I have a user control that's generating JavaScript for a chart. I'm trying to maintain ***some*** level of abstraction between the interface definition, and the code behind. I don't like the idea of breaking JSON standards, so I may address it from another angle. Thanks Marc.

Comment: Hahah, it's odd you should mention the `u` Marc. I found myself reflecting on this yesterday. I've since removed the `u` for consistency... although it hurts me a little.